# Remove all elements of an array with non-numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    ["b"] => banana
    [3] => cow
    ["wrench"] => duck
)
```

I want to take that array and use array_filter or something similar to remove elements with non-numeric keys and receive the follwoing array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [3] => cow
)
```

I was thinking about this, and I could not think of a way to do this because array_filter does not provide my function with the key, and array_walk cannot modify array structure (talked about in the PHP manual).

Comment: Does it matter if the key is a string representation of the number? i.e. `"0"`

Comment: Preferably, i would like to exclude that case, just be cause it seems more correct, but it does not matter in my current application.

Comment: doing more work than necessary is never "more correct"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using a [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach) loop would be appropriate in this case:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_int($key)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP newbie here. I had a 2D array, and I used this to update my inner loop. I could tell from print statements that the inner loop was being updated, but for some reason the entire 2D array stayed the same. I had to add another line at the end. So if the outer loop was `foreach ($everything as $index =>  $arr)`, you need `$everything[$index] = $arr;`.

Answer (score 25):

It can be done without writing a loop in **one** (long) **line**:

```
$a = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($a), 'is_numeric')));
```

> #### What it does:
>
> - Since `array_filter` works with values, `array_keys` first creates a new array with the keys as values (ignoring the original values).
> - These are then filtered by the `is_numeric` function.
> - The result is then *flipped* back so the keys are keys once again.
> - Finally, `array_intersect_key` only takes the items from the original array having a key in the result of the above (the numeric keys).

Don't ask me about performance though.

Comment: How can i check the array key not numeric. I am trying with is_string function in array_filter callback but getting an error

Comment: What error are you getting? As you can see here, this seems to work: https://3v4l.org/aj9FD

Comment: for sake of truth, `array_filter` actually is a loop. You are not "writing" a loop, but internally it is.

Comment: If you choose to use this answer, keep in mind that despite of `array_intersect_key` with `is_numeric` filter, you can simply use `is_string` filter.

Answer (score 25):

As of PHP 5.6, it's now possible to use `array_filter` in a compact form:

```
array_filter($array, function ($k) { return is_numeric($k); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

[Demo.](https://3v4l.org/7KjaV)

This approach is about 20% slower than a `for` loop on my box (1.61s vs. 1.31s for 1M iterations).

---

As of PHP 7.4, it's possible to also use short closures::

```
array_filter($array, fn($k) => is_numeric($k), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: You can also just pass the function name as a string.  I.e. `array_filter($array, "is_numeric", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a loop:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key !== 0 and !intval($key)) {
         unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because !intval(0) is true.